# Require and instanceof

Tags: node.js

Can someone please explain my why this happens and how to make it work correctly:

Imagine we have a module published on NPM called `test-module` with the following content:

```
function Class() {

}

module.exports = Class;
```

Then let's imagine our project folder looks like this:

```
[root]
-- child
```

and let's assume both the root and `child` folders have their own `npm` packages installed including our `test-module` module (same version of the module used in both folders).

Then we have the following files in the project:

```
// [root]/index.js

var Test = require("test-module");
var childTest = require("./child");

var one = new Test();

childTest(one);
```

and

```
// [root]/child/index.js

var Test = require("test-module");

var two = new Test();

module.exports = function(test) {
    console.log("#1:", test instanceof Test);
    console.log("#2:", two instanceof Test);
}
```

If we were to run `node index.js` on the root folder the result in the console is this:

```
#1: false
#2: true
```

### Question(s)

Shouldn't both `#1` and `#2` statements equal to `true`? Why the statement marked as `#1` in the console log equals to `false` even though `test` argument (`one`) is actually the instance of our `test-module` module, it just isn't installed in the same folder? Is there a way to make it work like this without some hackish solutions that came up to my mind?

Comment: getting error like gt is not defined when working with this module..How can I rectify this????

Comment: Does the child have it's own copy of `test-module` in `[root]/child/node-modules/test-module`?

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat: Yes, it has it's own copy but versions in both locations are same (e.g. 1.0.0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the problem is that you have two copies of the class in different files. Just because they are the same version doesn't mean Javascript will treat them the same. Node.js in particular doesn't really care about the version of the module and if there are other copies about it.

Even though they have the same name, for Javascript they are different classes. Because every time the class code executes, it'll be a unique function. You can observe it like this:

```
const ClassA = function SomeClass() {};
const ClassB = function SomeClass() {};
new ClassA() instanceof SomeClass // > false
```

Now you probably wonder what you have to do, to share the same exact module in your case. Normally what people do is to have only one copy of the module is installed on the root level and then specify the module version in the child with `peerDependencies` which npm ensures it matches. [Here's a good blog post about this issue](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/).

Comment: Actually that's a nice point you have there. Now what if we imagine further that our `child` folder/module is actually a published npm module (in which case structure would look something like this: `[root]/node_modules/child/node_modules/test-module`)? If I need to pass an instance of `test-module` from the root project to the `child` module, how can I test in the `child` module that the values passed into it is an instance of `test-module`?

Comment: I suggest use some sort of duck typing to do that instead. For example you can have a `isMySomeClass` property on your instance.

Comment: Yes, that was my idea also although it kind of kills the principle of nice code.  Anyway I got my answer. Thanks.